# Retrieving data from SQL database and inserting into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to allow users of a web app to secure their account by whitelisting IP addresses.

I have created a table in the relevant database, that records the following:

```
IPID (primary key) | owner | IP_Address
```

At the moment you can add IPs to the database, and the owner is automatically added using session data.

Now, in terms of protecting pages based on IP, I wanted to use something like:

```
$whitelist = array('111.111.111.111', '222.222.222.222');
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)) {
//Action for allowed IP Addresses
} else {
//Action for all other IP Addresses
echo 'You are not authorized here.'; 
echo "<br />IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
exit;
}
```

In the case above, the array is hard-coded, but I obviously want to use the data in my SQL database to populate the array. So in order to get the data, I can use something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT IP_Address FROM ITWhitelist WHERE owner=$userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        SafeIP = $row["IP_Address"];
    }
```

Being quite a novice, I'm not use how to combine the above approach with the SQL query and insert the data into the array. I'm familiar with looping through SQL outputs to create HTML, but not how to dynamically add SQL data to an array.

Can anyone help?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I am familiar with Prepared Statements. In this case, given that $userid is being retrieved from the server side session, is there still a risk of injection? There's no $_POST or $_GET data here.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Use placeholder values. Assumptions like this are how huge problems happen later on when the situation changes. A seemingly harmless modification to make `$userid` come from other source could have catastrophic consequences. Fixing the problem takes less time than you spent explaining why you didn't do it properly, there's no excuses.

Answer (score -1):

You should search for the address when going to the database so you don't need to build an array.

```
$allowed = false;
$sqldata = array(":user"=>$userid,":ipaddress"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$sql = "SELECT IP_Address FROM ITWhitelist WHERE owner = :user && IP_Address = :ipaddress";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["IP_Address"] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
            $allowed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if ($allowed)) {
    //Action for allowed IP Addresses
} else {
    //Action for all other IP Addresses
    echo 'You are not authorized here.'; 
    echo "<br />IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    exit;
}
```

As suggested by @tadman this is better than building the array and testing for the ip.

Note that my example above uses prepared statements, you may need to adjust it for your specific use but I recommend always using prepared statements.

Comment: This is still kind of broken as you should be able to see if the given address is in the whitelist table with one query, no need to even load any rows. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITWhitelist WHERE owner=? AND IP_Address=?`

Comment: I think the above should work, but I suspect you need to move the second if statement into the first, or you'll end up with an error in cases where there is no data in the DB and the array is empty. But if you nest it in the first if statement, the num_rows > 0 will deal with.

Comment: @tadman - thanks for the idea. I will explore more. I hadn't realised how easy it was to push SQL data into an array. Some of the stuff I'd read seemed to really over complicate it.